# Open Graph Error and Image Tag Not Rendering Properly

Tags: facebook-opengraph

We have a Wordpress site that uses a plugin to place Open Graph tags on our content. We receive the following error when using the FB linter:

Response Code:  200
Fetched URL:    facecrooks[dot]com/
Canonical URL:  facecrooks[dot]com/
Errors That Must Be Fixed

Body Meta:  You have meta tags outside of your head. This is either because your head was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree, or you accidentally put your Open Graph tags in the wrong place. Either way you need to fix it before the tags are usable.

We have not been able to locate any meta tags outside of the header.

Also, when we post an item from our website to our Facebook page a random image is selected instead of the one defined in the OG. Usually the image selected is a 125x125 ad from our right column.

You can verify that the Open Graph Tags are active on the site by visiting http://facecrooks.com and then view source.

Any idea on how to fix these errors would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe facebook's linter doesn't like the HTML div tags in the head section...

```
<noscript>

<div style="display:none;">

<img src="//pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-74ksBYx3WjrXU.gif" border="0" height="1" width="1" alt="Quantcast"/>

</div>

</noscript>
```